# Get specific(Azure) command details in powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

I need to get details of specific azure command(like create VM,remove VM and others) in power-shell.

for example to create VM we have "New-AzVM" command in power-shell.
I would like to know how we can get more help related to that command like

1. What are different types of arguments we can pass(like Authentication Arguments,Network Arguments and others)?
2. Which arguments are Required(Mandatory)?

*I know we can accomplish same thing in azure-CLI using "az vm create --help" command.*

Is there any command in power-shell which gives details of specific commands?(because I don't want to remember command(s) instead of that I would like to use "help" of powershell to get that command)

Note:- There is " Get-Command *New-AzVM*" command in powershell. but it list all command start with "New-AzVM".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [`Get-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help) cmdlet.

If you add the `-ShowWindow` switch, you will get a nice output in a new window:

```
Get-Help New-AzVM -ShowWindow
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [MS docs for the AZ module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/?view=azps-4.5.0) are pretty great as well. Plenty of examples and more detailed explanations of how things work. See the reference section in the left nav.